# elisp: print the length of string within insert

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to insert in a buffer the length of a lisp list as follows:

```
(insert "The list has " (length my-list) " elements")
```

However this produces a strange not printable character instead of the number of elements, so the result is something like

```
The list has ^A elements
```

Do I have to convert the return value? The list is not empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `format` function.

```
(insert (format "The list has %d elements" (length my-list)))
```

Alternatively, in this case, you can convert the integer to a string:

```
(insert "The list has " (number-to-string (length my-list)) " elements")
```

Control-A is ASCII code 1.  Apparently your list had one element when you tried.